# node promise - console prints the nested but cannot return value from firebase function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, promise, google-cloud-functions

Firstly, To be fair, I am neither a developer nor a reactjs or node expert. I love the functional programming and async nature that has drawn me to the javascript world. I am more of a pythonic person.

I have a firebase callable function . I can print the nested value with console.log but however have failed to return the value back to my react-redux app.

I strongly feel I am not using promises correctly. I am treating the promises to somehow return the values but am able to only do console.log on the value i want but fail to return it from firebase callable function

I have created the firebase callable function as following. Redux action invokes the firebase callable function. I get

// firebase callable function

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const dns = require('dns');
const util = require('util')


const getIP = function(domain) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dns.lookup(domain, (err, res) => {
            if(err) {
                reject(err)
            }
            if (res) {
                resolve(JSON.stringify(res))
            }
        })
    })
}

exports.getIP = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return {
    addresses: getIP(data.domain).then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
      return res
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
})
```

// react-redux store action

```
export const getIPAddress = (domain) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase}) => {
        const firebase = getFirebase();
        var dr = firebase.functions()

        dr({
            domain: domain
        }).then((result) => {
            console.log("check", result)
            dispatch({ type: 'IPADDRESS_SUCCESS', result: result});
        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch({ type: 'IPADDRESS_ERROR', err: err });
        })
    }
}
```

Expected output: ['ipaddress1', 'ipaddress2']

Current output: object

```
data:
addresses:
domain: {domain: null, _events: {…}, _eventsCount: 1, _maxListeners: null, members: Array(0)}
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
type: "IPADDRESS_SUCCESS"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const dns = require('dns');
const util = require('util')


const getIP = function(domain) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dns.lookup(domain, (err, res) => {
            if(err) {
                reject(err)
            }
            if (res) {
                resolve(res)
            }
        })
    })
}

exports.getIP = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
     try {
       return {
         addresses: await getIP(data.domain)
       };
     } catch (err) {
       console.log(err);
     }

})
```

Comment: Irvin, 

This was very helpful. The issue is now resolved for me. I am going to use your pattern more often. 

I have made one change, I removed the JSON.stringify. 

One more thing to check was to avoid NodeJS 10 for Firebase functions. Nodejs 10 is still beta per google on gcp. Do not know how it kept breaking my authentication.